# How to make a toolbar which have TextView and show above Keyboard when Button Tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitoolbar

I know there are some questions about how to show a toolbar above keyboard.
I read some of them. But, I could not make the toolbar which have TextView like message app. I want to make a toolbar which is showed when button tapped.
I also use IB to create a toolbar because I need some adjustment to appearance.

The code now I make is below.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *ibToolbar;
// this text view is subview of ibToolbar
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *barTextView; 
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.ibToolbar removeFromSuperview];
    self.barTextView.inputAccessoryView = self.ibToolbar;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender {
    [self.barTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

When I tap the button, I want to look at toolbar above keyboard to put text on textView.
But, nothing happened when I push the button.

I think that why this code does not work, also because the viewController's view does not parent view of the toolbar,so [self.barTextView becomeFirstResponder] can not be effective.
I think that something else which I did is needed to work the things.
If anyone know do the things work, please tell me.

Comment: can you show your `ViewController` from the story board?

Comment: Yes, ViewController is showed from the story board.